# graphql-java field resolver with multiple java objects

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java

I'm new to GraphQL and graphql-java.
I have a schema with fields coming from two(or more) services.
Schema looks something like this.

```
type Payload {
    price: Price
}

type Price {
   sellerPrice: String
   offerPrice: String
}
```

`sellerPrice` comes from one service in the following JSON format

```
{
 seller": {
     "seller_price": "10.00"
   }
}
```

`offerPrice` comes from another service with the following format.

```
{
 "offer": {
     "offer_price": "8.00"
   }
}
```

I'm struggling to figure out how to create a resolver that will auto resolve the services based on the requested attributes(sellerPrice and/or offerPrice).
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am not sure to understand your question. To retrieve data from the graphql interface you will need to define a Query, define the expected input/output, and then wire a datafetcher that will resolve the query.